# While generating SSH key in GitHub, It is creating only private key public key is absent?

Tags: github

Problem: Only id_rsa is generated.
**id_rsa.pub** is absent

I was generating SSH key in github using

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C " myemail@gmail.com
```

Tried to generate ssh key while pushing a project into repository in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a public key from the provate one:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Check your version of openssh though.
Try, for testing (without passphrase)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f test
```

That should generate a `test` and `test.pub` key pair.